For a a cover letter what's an appropriate salutation line for someone I know but have had a disagreement with
A colleague in a university department where I previously held a temporary position recently notified me of a job posting for which I am a good match. According to the job posting, which was signed by the person (who is also the department head) who hired me for my previous role, he is now handling this application.
As a result of a minor disagreement before I left, we haven't been in touch since my previous contract expired. I don't know how he handled it and what he thinks of my performance. As part of my previous tenure, we had a casual relationship.
While I intend to apply, I'm unsure however what salutation I should use.
Should I pretend I am applying without knowing him and use 'dearX' or should it be casual, and if so, what is an appropriate casual salutation in this case?
I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Modern solution: Skip the salutation entirely. It's just a formalism, and adds little unless you are trying to add something. Otherwise, "Dear Professor Whatever" is accepted as not actually meaning that they are dear to you. Or just use their name without qualifier.

This is really about writing formalisms, not workplace as such; the answers wouldn't change much if the person was at a completely separate  institution, or if this was personal rather than professional correspondence.

Name without qualifier is a reasonable middle way for a situation like this. Yes, it's formalistic, but it's a finicky situation given the history I have with this person.   Thanks for your input.

Where abouts in the world are you? A name without a qualifier actually comes off as quite rude to me, but I know it's accepted in other parts of the world.

I think this question can only be answered if you tell the community in which location, region, city you are applying. The formality is a cultural feature and can be best answered when we know the culture it takes place.

In spite of living in Canada for 13 years, I still seem to be influenced by the culture I grew up in in Sweden. For good or bad, there are no salutations, dears, sirs, or even Mr./Ms in that part of the world..

You use a greeting that is professional and warm.  It will indicate that you have moved on from the disagreement and you don't remember or carry grudges.
'Greetings Dr. Smith' or 'Dear Dr. Smith' or whatever you normally use for a salutation.  Since you know him, you can make some nice reference to that, but do not mention the disagreement in the cover letter, nor give any indication that it is on your mind.  (Unless you were in the wrong!  In that case, a passing apology could be ok, but it should still be quick and not the focus of the letter.)

has the best answer IMHO. There is value in being nice, no value in reminding of anything bad. This is speaking from experience.

My go-to is from the old Bloom County comic strip, “Attention Criminal Pervert.”

Or you could use a normal greeting and not let whatever beef you have make you behave unprofessionally.  Your call.

I'm sorry, I don't feel I can upvote this because it is not really helpful to the OP. But it is hilarious. Thanks for the day-brightener.

@MarkMeuer: Is it not? It seems to suggest they should write down what comes to their mind by mere gut feeling first, then replace each statement with something else that at least touches upon the same topic, but expressed in polite wording, and then go with the result.

@O.R.Mapper :  It hadn't occurred to me it was a serious suggestion.  But I like how you're interpreting it.  Upvoting the answer.

@MarkMeuer and O.R yeah perhaps that's true, but currently the post comes out a bit sarcastic or the suggestion is not explicit (one has to "read between the lines" a bit). Thats why this post could benefit of making a synopsis of the real message in text at the end of the answer

@DarkCygnus I can't even read the text in that image, forget reading between the lines...

I am a believer in face-to-face or even voice calls, rather than txt or emails.  Since you used to know him, give him a call or if practical, go and visit him.  Then apply for the position.
There is a chance that he may want to smooth things over as well.
For the letter/email, use "Professor x".  Dear is up to you, I still use it.  But if you want to bury the hatchet, you need to NOT show disrespect.  So, use the title.

This first part is the best answer. Confront any potential awkwardness head on. This person has the power the torpedo your job application, but they also have the power to give you a referral and give you the inside scoop. Give them a call. Or give them a ping on LinkedIn and then give them a call. Now as to the last paragraph, I believe this is largely culture-dependent. Personally, I would never call a friend "Professor x" unless I was teasing them or introducing them to a crowd.

Even when 2 professors or doctors strongly disagree with each other about many things, they will still address each other as "Professor XYZ" or "Dr. ABC".
That is simply a matter of being professional.


As a result of a minor disagreement before I left,...

If this is truly a minor disagreement as you said, both of you should have forgotten about it, or let it go a long time ago.
It is safe to assume that both of you are adults, and in the position of educators (University professors). Is that right ?
So, go ahead and use "Dear Professor XYZ" or something similar to that as other answers suggest.

(BTW, even children love the song "Let It Go" from the Disney's movie "Frozen".)
